# How come using import SQL only works if the insert script is the only script in the SQL pane?

Tags: csv, sql

I am going to take a shot here and hope that some of you in superuser actually use SQLA (SQL Assistant).

When you set `File > Import Data` so that you can execute `insert into mydb.mytable (?,?,?,?);` to import a CSV, it only seems to work if that insert statement is the only statement in the entire code pane.  I have SQLA set up to execute the selected query, but even selecting that insert statement fails if other SQL exists in the pane.  I have to copy the SQL to a new pane and run it for it to work.  Even if I comment out all the other SQL in the pane, it still fails.  What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using SQLA for 2 years now and Import works just as you mentioned it should.

However, try this:

1. Right-click on the shortcut to SQLA and run as administrator
2. Go to Tools>Options
3. Uncheck the "Submit only the selected query text, when highlighted" option in Query tab
4. Quit SQLA
5. Right-click on the shortcut to SQLA and run as administrator
6. Go to Tools>Options
7. Check the "Submit only the selected query text, when highlighted" option in Query tab

Highlight your import statement and press F5 (execute query).

[image: SQLA Options]